# Get mongodb subDocument

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb

consider the following data

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("580bc94b221036257caf2636"),
"Status" : "Scheduled",
//I want to get this Questions list
"Questions" : [ 
    {
        "QuestionType" : "Choice",
        "Question" : "What is your name?",
        "Correct" : "C",
        "Options" : [ 
            "xxx", 
            "xxx", 
            "xxx"
        ]
    },
{
        "QuestionType" : "Choice",
        "Question" : "What is your name?",
        "Correct" : "C",
        "Options" : [ 
            "xxx", 
            "xxx", 
            "xxx"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Here is my query

```
var collection = mongodb.GetCollection<QuestionsList>("Papers");
        var choice = collection.Find(Query.EQ("userName", "Sohail")).SetFields(Fields.Exclude("status")
            .Slice("Questions", 1)).Single();
        return choice.multiQuestions.ToList();
```

I am trying this for the past one week but nothing seems to be working
My question is how I can get this Questions List and display it to my MVC view??
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly it appear you are querying a Username field on your document which you do not appear to have based on the data structure you have provided above:

```
.Find(Query.EQ("userName", "Sohail"))
```

But assuming this was a typo...

You can  use $project here to return the Embedded array of questions:

```
var collection = mongodb.GetCollection<QuestionsList>("Papers");

var projection = Builders<QuestionsList>.Projection.Include("Questions");
var choice = collection
                 .Find(Query.EQ("userName", "Sohail"))
                 .Project(projection)
                 .ToList();

return choice;
```

It looks like you have a C# model (QuestionsList) so is there any reason you are not using the strongly typed querying? Assuming your models looks like this:

```
public class QuestionsList
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    //Missing from your data structure but assume it is there
    public string userName { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public string QuestionType { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Correct { get; set; }
    public List<string> Options { get; set; }
}
```

The equivalent would be

```
var choice = collection
                 .Find(x => x.userName == "Sohail"))
                 .Project(x => x.Questions)
                 .ToList();
```